# Loading MySQL Table into Cache (and process data) vs constantly sending queries

Tags: java, mysql

Im currently developing a Java Server Application which has a lot of tables with some data that is modified frequently. All of the data has to get often fully retrieved (to display it to the user or to index it). As MySQL queries seem to be expensive (and problematic because I need the data async) I came up with the idea of literally loading in the entire table as a local cache. That way I can index the data always from the local cache and I only need to send changes to the mysql. Fortunately the data is not that big so I dont have to worry about OutOfMemory Exceptions.

**What is more efficient, repeatingly sending queries to MySQL or load all data in local cache to do operations?**

Thanks for reading,
Regards, Tech!

Comment: You might start your research here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/memory-storage-engine.html

Comment: I also have to wonder if, since your MySQL driver doesn't support asynchronous access, and performance is not good enough (You HAVE measured where the latency is, yes? It would be a drag to change your database architecture and discover the problem was elsewhere...), why you are using MySQL at all. It may be too late for a major change in your project, but Redis sounds more like the tool for you.

Comment: I havent measured performance at all to be honest. The current solution works pretty fine to me. Unfortunately I have to stick with MySQL because my customers only have that option.

Comment: Then I would say that in general, the usual query caching techniques should work for you, along with judicious use of prepared statements for queries you use a lot. But it's really hard to generalize.